# python rtype docstring/restructured text for class factories/selectors

Tags: python, pycharm, restructuredtext, docstring

`:rtype:` specifies that this is the type of the returned object.

Therefore, when I create the object `obj` in the following snippet I receive a warning from the IDE that `cls is not callable`, since the IDE expects that `cls` is `object` of type `SomeAbstractClass`, and I want `SomeAbstractClass` itself.

The IDE is right, since this is the default behaviour. But how can I specify that I am returning a class, not an instance of a class?

Specifying `type` instead of `SomeAbstractClass` helps a bit, but that's not a solution, since no further introspection is available.

```
def class_selector(data):
    """
    :rtype: SomeAbstractClass
    :return: Return some class based on given parameters
    """
    
    return get_from.get(data.name)
cls = class_selector(data)
obj = cls(data.more_data)
```

Meanwhile I have solved this by adding  `""":type: SomeAbstractClass"""` after object creating, but this does not cancel the warning and it's a dirty solution.

By the way, I am talking about Python 2.x.

Comment: since the `:rtype:` annotation is meant to indicate the `type()` of the return value, and since `type(SomeAbstractClass)` is `type`, you should perhaps use `:rtype: type`?

Comment: Thank you for input, but i've specified in the question why this approach does not work, type = creator of default object class. Without class-specific attributes, so this wont allow further introspection and validation, this provides IDE only with knowledge, that it is some class, not specific one

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or find more advice on writing Python docstrings for Pycharm? Really enjoying Pycharm lately and would love to see more examples of writing good docstrings to help Pycharm inspect code.

Comment: I know the question is two years old but here is the list of supported docstring type hints
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#legacy
what you can use is `type[SomeAbstractClass]` that is type parmetrized with your class

Comment: Please have a look at this python issue, where Guido explains: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/58

Answer (score 1):

As for 2020, the only solution that is working properly - using python3 annotations:

Which in general is totally acceptable for 2020

Attaching a screenshot to demonstrate the correct behavior.
Basically, `def factory(name) -> type[SomeAbstractClass]:` or `def factory(name) -> "type[SomeAbstractClass]":` (for cases when can't import the name) works totally fine.

Still could not come up with a solution for older Python versions (i.e avoiding the use of annotations). But it's not a deal-breaker in 2020

[image: correct_behaviour]

And same code as text, if anyone wants to copy-paste to test alternative approaches

```
class SomeAbstractClass:
    property_by_class = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.property_by_object = 1


def factory(name) -> type[SomeAbstractClass]:
    hide_it = dict()
    class ActualClassImpl(SomeAbstractClass):
        pass
    hide_it.__setitem__(name, ActualClassImpl)
    return hide_it.__getitem__(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = factory('testclass')
    by_class_should_be_ok = a.property_by_class
    by_object_should_hint_error = a.property_by_object
    just_like_none_existing_property_hints = a.property_by_object_bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of Python 3.6.9, it might be not be comfortable but as you said yourself this is the correct notation:

```
"""
:return: subclass of SomeAbstractClass
:rtype: type
"""
```

rtype defines the type of the thing to be returned. I don't see any space left for discussions here.

Comment: it does not work, it should be not general type, it should be specifically SomeAbstractClass class. And if you put it into rtype - Pycharm will consider it object of this type, not type itself

Comment: Well type is the metaclass of SomeAbstractClass, which means that SomAbstractClass is an object (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python). Therefore I regard this as correct. BTW speaking of Python 3.6.9

Answer (score -4):

if the data is an instance of SomeAbstractClass, you can use the following snippets:

example 1:

```
def class_selector(data):
    """
    return: Return the class of data
    """

    return type(data)
```

example 2:

```
def class_selector(data):
    """
    return: Return the class of data.
    """

    return data.__class__
```

And if you want use data.name to specify a class, you can use this:

```
def class_selector(data):
   """
   return: Return a class specified by data.name
   """
   return type(globals()[data.name])  #or use globals()[data.name].__class__
```

and you should catch the KeyError exception when you use this

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question. Question is how to specify in docstring that return value is class, not actually return the class, since this is not the problem.