# How to specify that method returns specific class, not instance

Tags: python, pycharm

I know that it's possible to specify return types in PyCharm like this:

```
def func(x):
    """
    Compute square of x. 
    :type x: int
    :rtype: int 
    """
    return x**x
```

But how would I hint that my function is returning a class, not an instance? I've tried something like:

```
:rtype: type of Class
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you show your actual code, not this example snippet?

Comment: you can try `classobj` as rtype if your project is only for Python2. classtype has changed between python2 and 3

Comment: Found very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593560/python-rtype-docstring-restructured-text-for-class-factories-selectors

Comment: A class is an instance of `type`, you could use that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that what's I've tried and it didn't helped much.

Comment: *"didn't helped"*... what, exactly?

Comment: Also note that new-style classes **are** types.